# about the principal component analysis using M3C package

Tags: r, pca

I would like to conduct a principal component analysis using the M3C package.

```
library(M3C)
iris
pca(iris[,c(1:4)])
```

This works, but

```
library(M3C)   
iris$Species<-as.character(iris$Species)
pca(iris[,c(1:4)],labels =iris$Species)
```

I got an error message saying "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): colour"

Could you tell me any solutions?

Comment: Try `iris[,1:4]`

Comment: This package is a bit weird. performs pca on the rows. I guess you have to do pca(t(iris[,c(1:4)]),labels =iris$Species) or pca(iris[,c(1:4)),labels =colnames(iris)[1:4])

Comment: It does that because it is a bioconductor package, in bioinformatics, samples are usually columns and rows features.

Comment: Thank you so much!!